# Could not load file or assembly System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe - when reference dll file from another project

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework-core, nuget-package, unsafe

I add an entity framework project to a solution and reference it to the existing project(referencing the project throws errors because the existing project have .NET Framework and the entity framework project have .NET Core , so i referenced the dll of the entity framework project.

The exception :

System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.'

I try to use bindingRedirect but its not worked for me.
from app config :

```
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.0.0.0" newVersion="5.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
```

I read several solutions but none of them worked for me.

Comment: are you referencing .net core project to .net framework project?

Comment: On deploy machine you need to load the runtime version of Net.  See : https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet?force_isolation=true

Comment: yes referencing .net core project to .net framework project , but dll file , not the whole project because it throws error.

Comment: often it's better if you convert the .net core project to a **.net standard** one, then import should be ok.

Comment: Hi Lei , when i try to convert to .net standard it throws errors. my core project is for entity framework db usage , lot of interfaces is used in the migrations. you have any idea how i can i fix it ?

Comment: there's more than one way to do that. i often find myself need convert target .net platform too. the final option is to create a new project first, then gradually add the rest, before adding you make sure compile and run smoothly.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was due to the use of a DLL file associated with a project that uses a .net core as opposed to a project that uses a .net framework.

I upgraded to .net core and the issue was resolved.

Comment: You may want to mark your answer as accepted to indicate that this question needs no more answers.